# Reaction between Sudan IV and lipids

Tags: reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

The Sudan IV is a molecule used to detect lipids in a substance, especially the triglycerides. The Sudan IV molecule formula is  $\ce{C24H20N4O}$ and a triglyceride molecule could have this molecule formula $\ce{C55H98O6}$.

When the two solutions are mixed, there is a color change. What causes this? I assume that it is because a new compound is produced and this compound is red colored.

Is it possible to find the chemical equation of the reaction between Sudan IV and triglyceride?

Comment: The fact that it is sparingly soluble in water but v soluble in lipids means that it concentrates in lipid which is why its colour appears stronger. It does not significantly change colour on entering the lipid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's how Sudan IV works. Sudan IV is a highly conjugated aromatic diazo compound, so it is already highly colored. In the lipid, the Sudan IV is basically hydrophobic so it will stain any lipid droplets suspended in water. The color is due purely to the Sudan IV, not a reaction.